# WebKit vs. Firefox CSS

Tags: css, firefox, safari

I'm having an issue with CSS on Chrome, Safari, and WebKit vs. Firefox.

On Firefox, a background image which is the size of a table row looks proper. On Chrome the edges cut off.

http://stage.schoolforcreativestartups.com/fees-funding/

How can I fix it?

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="background-image: url('http://stage.schoolforcreativestartups.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/yello‌​w_stripe.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center top;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <td style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px; padding-top:14px;padding-left:12px;color:#5A5494">
            Angel Society Bursary<br></td>
        <td>&pound;1,000<br></td>
        <td>&pound;2,500<br></td>
        <td>Unlimited*<br></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should put the CSS and HTML here

Comment: Not here man... in the question, as every user does. it look like compressed HTML5 and it's unreadable

Comment: Sorry, I've ammended my post. Thanks for your feedback.

A few notes: This is not HTML5 but tables which are simple HTML (3 or 4).

Also, it's not compressed. If you're mentioning its minifcation, SO does that automatically.

Again, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I suggest changing the title to summarize the issue, it's not really descriptive right now...

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I came across another Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958366/css-webkit-background-images-for-table-row), but you could also do this:

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <table style="background-image: url('http://stage.schoolforcreativestartups.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/yello‌​w_stripe.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center top;border-collapse:collapse;">
     <tr>
       <td style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px; padding-top:14px;padding-left:12px;color:#5A5494">
        Angel Society Bursary<br></td>
      <td>&pound;1,000<br></td>
      <td>&pound;2,500<br></td>
      <td>Unlimited*<br></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </td>
 <td>&pound;1,000<br></td>
 <td>&pound;2,500<br></td>
 <td>Unlimited*<br></td>
</tr>
```